# child_process.fork is not working and idk the reason

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use child_process.fork() but it's not working. I tried using spawn and that works. Can anyone help me?

```html
 child_process.fork('node', ["bot.js"],{cwd:fs.readFileSync('./path.txt')+"\\Workroom\\"});
```

Answer (score 0):

`readFileSync` is returning a buffer when you expect it to return a string. You need to set the encoding to 'utf8'. And I recommend using `path.join` instead of simply concatenating (assuming the content of *path.txt* is a valid path). your code would look something like this...

```
child_process.fork('node', ["bot.js"],
    {cwd: path.join(fs.readFileSync('./path.txt', 'utf8'),'Workroom')}
);
```